# How to use wider and higher margins in a beamerboxesrounded box?

Tags: beamer, boxes

I love beamerboxesrounded boxes in Beamer presentations, but the text fits too tightly into the box. So I would like to use equal but wider and higher margins (left, right, top, bottom) around the text, or padding inside the box. How is it possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the package [`tcolorbox`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox) which provides several keys for customization of margins, padding and so on.

Here are few examples:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\tcbset{beamer,colback=blue!20!white,colframe=blue!75!black}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Some boxes}
\begin{tcolorbox}[title=Title]
block text
\end{tcolorbox}

\begin{tcolorbox}[title=Title,boxsep=3mm]
block text
\end{tcolorbox}

\begin{tcolorbox}[title=Title, size=small]
block text
\end{tcolorbox}

\begin{tcolorbox}[title=Title, width=4cm,size=fbox]
block text
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

More details in the package documentation.

Comment: Thanks! Another question: I would like to use frame style, but I do not know what kind of packages have to be loaded.

Comment: The best way to thank is to upvote the answer and mark it as accepted by clicking on the green mark below the vote arrows. For the other question: could you please detail more what you mean with `frame style`? AFAIK with tcolorbox you can customize the frame style as you wish, hence more information is really needed.

Answer (score 1):

You could take the tcolorbox inner theme as starting point and modify the padding from there:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw} 

\useinnertheme{tcolorbox}

\tcbset{
  boxsep=5mm
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame} 
        \begin{block}{Title} 
            Preface 
        \end{block} 
    \end{frame} 
\end{document}
```

[image]